# building software using bazel is slower than make?

Tags: makefile, bazel

My team has a project which is not too big, built by make -js, cost 40 seconds, when using bazel, the time incresed to 70 secs. And here is the profile of the build process of bazel. I noticed that SKYFUNCTION takes 47% of the time cost, is that reasonable?

---

## PROFILES

## the last section of it:

```
Type    Total   Count   Average
ACTION  0.03%   77  0.70 ms
ACTION_CHECK    0.00%   4   0.90 ms
ACTION_EXECUTE  40.40%  77  912 ms
ACTION_UPDATE   0.00%   74  0.02 ms
ACTION_COMPLETE 0.19%   77  4.28 ms
INFO    0.00%   1   0.05 ms
VFS_STAT    1.07%   117519  0.02 ms
VFS_DIR 0.27%   4613    0.10 ms
VFS_MD5 0.22%   151 2.56 ms
VFS_DELETE  4.43%   53830   0.14 ms
VFS_OPEN    0.01%   232 0.11 ms
VFS_READ    0.06%   3523    0.03 ms
VFS_WRITE   0.00%   4   0.97 ms
WAIT    0.05%   156 0.56 ms
SKYFRAME_EVAL   6.23%   1   10.830 s
SKYFUNCTION 47.01%  687 119 ms
```

Comment: 1. I don’t know, not a bazel member.

Comment: Sorry, enter pressed two soon. 2. Not sure bazel aims to be faster for every project, this sounds like a small project. 3. See thread about skylark performance in bazel-dev over on google groups

Comment: Skyfunctions are a key component in Bazel's incrementality model, [Skyframe](https://bazel.build/designs/skyframe.html). Make uses [timestamps](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.61/html_node/Timestamps-and-Make.html). It's reasonable to expect Skyfunctions occupying a large proportion of the total build time. It's difficult, however, to pinpoint why Bazel is slower than Make in your project, without any insight about how your project is structured.

Comment: Other goodies apart when speaking pure speed, on small enough projects make is really hard to beat and that applies to bazel as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ittai, @Jin, @Ondrej K, I have tried to switched off the sandboxing in bazel, it seems much faster than with it switched on. here is the comparison:

- SWITCHED ON:  70s
- SWITCHED OFF: 33s±2

the skyFunction still takes 47% of all the execution time. but the everage times it takes turned from 119ms to 21ms.